# How to add a new version of a AWS service catalog product using cloud formation template?

Tags: aws-service-catalog

if I deploy the following cloud formation template for the first time, it successfully creates the product with version v1.0 (as the template shows)

```
SomeProduct:
    Type: AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProduct
    Properties:
      Description: something
      Name: Some Name
      Owner: Me
      ProvisioningArtifactParameters:
        - Info:
            LoadTemplateFromURL:
              Fn::
                - https://something.s3.amazonaws.com/somes3key
                - {}
          Name: v1.0
```

If I want to add a new version and change Name to v1.1, for example, it also deploys successfully, however it deletes v1.0 and I don't want that. If you do via AWS console you can add a new version and keep both. I couldn't find any doc about that. Has anyone had this issue?

I checked https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-servicecatalog-cloudformationproduct.html and I don't see a way of doing that.